# How to exlude a directory

Tags: powershell

i'm a beginner on powershell scripting so keep cool ^^

I would like to delete file on directory d:\test I delete only file more 15 days
but I'don't want to delete files on another directory in directory d:\test.

My script

```
#----- define parameters -----#
#----- get current date ----#
$Now = Get-Date
#----- define amount of days ----#
$Days = "15"
#----- define folder where files are located ----#
$TargetFolder = "d:\test"
#----- define extension ----#
$Extension = "*.bak"
#----- define LastWriteTime parameter based on $Days ---#
$LastWrite = $Now.AddDays(-$Days)
#----- get files based on lastwrite filter and specified folder ---#
$Nomatch = "d:\test\ZZ - Archives","d:\test\ZZ - Cloture Paye"

$Files = Get-Childitem $TargetFolder -Include $Extension -Recurse | Where {$_.LastWriteTime -le "$LastWrite"} | 
Where-Object {$_.FullName -notmatch "$Nomatch"}

foreach ($File in $Files)
        {
        if ($File -ne $NULL)
            {
            write-host "Deleting File $File" -ForegroundColor "DarkRed"
            Remove-Item $File.FullName | out-null
            }
        else
            {
            Write-Host "No more files to delete!" -foregroundcolor "Green"
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are on Powershell 2.0, to get only files:

```
Get-ChildItem $TargetFolder | Where-Object { ! $_.PSIsContainer }
```

If you are on Powershell 3.0, do:

```
Get-ChildItem $TargetFolder -File
```

I don't know if you want `-Recurse`. If you want only files at `d:\test` and not the files under child directories too, don't use `-Recurse`.

Comment: Sorry but it's not my question I just want to exclude I know i can use PSIcontainer but it s possible to have line of code for that ?

Comment: @Stranger - Sorry, I can't understand your comment. Have line of code for what?

Comment: about that for exclude my specific directory see below            $Files = Get-Childitem $TargetFolder -Include $Extension -Recurse |
where { !$_.PSIsContainer } | ...

Answer (score 1):

There is a property on each file

```
PSIsContainer
```

It indicates if your object is a directory and you can filter your files collection:

```
$Files = Get-Childitem $TargetFolder -Include $Extension -Recurse |
where { !$_.PSIsContainer } | ...
```

Comment: I can exclude directory with psiscontainer ? with which line of code ?

Comment: Ok I find a solution about my case ^^